# Dynamic Action<T> : Invalid Arguments when executed

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, types

I have a lot of places in my decently sized project where I need to switch on a type.  Obviously I can't do that in .NET (in a way simple enough to satisfy me), so I have to do a decent amount of casting.  This code is the result of trying to hide some of that in a proof of concept.

I have a simple inheritence modeled:

```
public class Base { }
public class Derived : Base { public string Name { get; set; } }
```

and my class:

```
public sealed class TypeSwitch<T> 
{
    private Dictionary<Type, dynamic> _dict;

    public TypeSwitch()
    {
        _dict = new Dictionary<Type, dynamic>();
    }

    public TypeSwitch<T> Add<K>(Action<K> action) where K : T
    {
        _dict.Add(typeof(K), action);
        return this;
    } 

    public void Execute(T item)
    {
        var type = item.GetType();
        var action = _dict[type];

        action(item);
    }
}
```

and I run it with:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ts = new TypeSwitch<Base>();
    ts.Add<Derived>(d => { Console.WriteLine(d.Name); });

    Base b = new Derived { Name = "Jonesopolis" };
    ts.Execute(b);
}
```

When I get to `action(item)` I get a `RuntimeBinderException` saying

> Additional information: Delegate 'System.Action<ConsoleApp.Derived>' has some invalid arguments

This would be pretty slick and helpful if I could get it working.  Can someone explain to me what I'm missing?  Is it possible to get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try another level of lambdas. In addition to working, I expect this would be considerably faster than using `dynamic`, even though there are two delegates being invoked.

```
public sealed class TypeSwitch<T>
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Action<T>> _dict; // no longer dynamic

    public TypeSwitch()
    {
        _dict = new Dictionary<Type, Action<T>>();  // no longer dynamic
    }

    public TypeSwitch<T> Add<K>(Action<K> action) where K : T
    {
        _dict.Add(typeof (K), o => action((K) o)); // outer lambda casts the value before calling the inner lambda
        return this;
    }

    public void Execute(T item)
    {
        var type = item.GetType();
        var action = _dict[type];
        action(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, don't think I would've ever tried that.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Any idea how you would do a Remove of `Action<K>` ?

Answer (score 8):

Your `item` parameter is not `dynamic`. Because it's statically typed as `T`, that type `T` (which happens to be `Base`) will be used for overload resolution. `Action<Derived>` cannot be invoked with a `Base` argument.

To use `dynamic` here, you need to make `item` `dynamic` too: change `action(item);` to `action((dynamic) item);`.