# Visual Studio C# shortcut for cast followed by check for null

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I find that I write code like this pretty often:

```
public void some_callback(object sender, SomeArgs args)
{
    if (sender is ObjectA)
    {
        var objA = sender as ObjectA;
        //do something
    }
    else if (sender is ObjectB)
    {
        var objB = sender as ObjectB;
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Or similarly:

```
public void some_callback(object sender, SomeArgs args)
{
    var objA = sender as ObjectA;
    if (objA != null)
    {
        //do something
    }

    var objB = sender as ObjectB;
    if (objB != null)
    {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

What I would like to know is if there is a shortcut way to handle this in C#? Something along the lines of:

```
public void some_callback(object sender, SomeArgs args)
{
    with (var obj = sender as ObjectA)
    {
        //do something
    }
    else with (var obj = sender as ObjectB)
    {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just create an overloaded method that takes precedence over the "object" signature?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I suppose so. The callback function was intended to be more of a use case of the example. I am more interested in the program flow, as noted by the question. This "cast followed by check for null" is a common pattern that I use in many different scenarios, not just for callbacks. Event handlers and callbacks just seem to be common use cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are asking is essentially the pattern matching that will be added in C# 7.0. See the [notes](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/future/docs/features/patterns.md#type-pattern). You will be able to write:

```
if (expr is Type v) { // code using v }
```

But that's for the next version.

Comment: Upvoted, although the contents of C# 7.0 is still speculative.

Comment: I'm +1'ing this too, because I think it answers my question. You're essentially saying "it is not currently supported, but it might be coming in later versions".

Comment: Yes, if you are looking for a 'nice syntax' for this type of checks pattern matching should fit well.

Answer (score 2):

We needed this in our code too, so with [the help of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32512153/dynamic-actiont-invalid-arguments-when-executed) I created a `TypeSwitch` object:

```
public sealed class TypeSwitch<T>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<T>> _dict;

    public TypeSwitch()
    {
        _dict = new Dictionary<Type, Action<T>>();
    } 

    public TypeSwitch<T> Add<TChild>(Action<TChild> action) where TChild : T
    {
        _dict.Add(typeof (TChild), o => action((TChild) o));
        return this;
    }

    public void Execute(T item)
    {
        var type = item.GetType();

        foreach (var kvp in _dict)
        {
            if (type == kvp.Key || kvp.Key.IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                kvp.Value(item);
                return;
            }
        }

        throw new KeyNotFoundException($"{type} or its baseclass not located in typeswitch.");
    }
}
```

which you can use like:

```
var obj = new BaseClass();

new TypeSwitch<BaseClass>()
       .Add<Derived1>(d1 => { /*strongly typed d1 action */ })
       .Add<Derived2>(d2 => { /*strongly typed d2 action */ })
       .Execute(obj);
```

It's been pretty handy for us.  Worth noting that it's not set up as-is for any asynchronous operations, but could be modified to be pretty easily.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does this impact debugging? It seems like it would make things more difficult to step through, and harder to see the program flow.

Comment: hasn't been much of a problem.  you can figure out what type you have before the switch, then set a breakpoint in the correct action.